# Add properties to property placeholder

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring, properties

I have an application where a property placeholder is used to read properties, configured in `applicationContext.xml`:

```
...
<context:property-placeholder
     location="classpath*:META-INF/spring/*.properties"/> 
...
```

The application runs in an Tomcat and uses the parameter defined in context.xml.
The application access this parameter like normal properties (`@Value(${cfma.applicationUrl})`). *This works*

In my test cases I do not have this tomcat properties, so I want to add them "manually" to the application context. But also load the normal `applicationContext.xml`

testContext.xml:

```
<import resource="classpath:/META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml" />
<context:property-placeholder properties-ref="simulatedTomcatProperties"/>
<util:properties id="simulatedTomcatProperties">
   <prop key="cfmt.applicationBaseUrl">localhost:8080/cfmt</prop>
</util:properties>
```

Now I have two context:property-placeholder and this does not work (of course) – **So my question is, who can I extend the properties in the “normal” property-placeholder in my test?**

---

More Explanation of what I need:

- The productive environment (as well as the development environment) defines some properties via Tomcat parameter. Therefore they are not included in any properties file, but nerveless they can be accessed like normal properties (`@Value(${cfma.applicationUrl})`). Moreover there must not be any Fallback, if the properties are not defined in the Tomcat, the application must not start!
- In the test cases (that use the spring context) I must some how insert the property (cfma.applicationUrl) so that it can be injected in the annotated variables.
  But if I add an second `context:property-placeholder` they are not merged:

@See Comments on https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-4881 -- they explain that behaviour.

---

When I talk about Tomcat parameter I am talking about somethink like this:

context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context>
    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
    <Parameter name="cfmt.applicationBaseUrl"
          value="http://localhost/demoApp" override="false"/>
</Context>
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6375016/spring-properties-file-setting-default-values It effectively allows you to define multiple properties locations. Missing properties files are ignored, and the last valid file listed is loaded.

Comment: @Filip: My question is not about multiple location. I get stucked with multiple property placeholder configurer. And I am looking for a way to extend/change the configuration of the "normal" app context property placeholder configurer from my test-context.xml

Comment: Sorry. My comment wasn't very clear, I wasn't suggesting a way of specifying multiple properties files, but a way of doing conditional properties lookups. An expanded answer is below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure if this will help, but what I do in a similar situation is have 2 app.properties files with the same name, one in sec/test/resources and the other in src/main/resources. Now during testing the first is loaded because the test classes are first on the classpath, but when I deploy only the main one is there and so it is loaded.

Comment: Because my problem belongs to additional properties my workaround is to have an additional properties file for my tests in test/resources (Maven bases project).

Comment: Yes, I do end up duplicating properties in the two files!

Answer (score 3):

Does it work if you add the same `location` attribute to the `context:property-placeholder` defined in `testContext.xml` that is in the one defined in `applicationContex.xml`? You would also need to add the attribute `local-override="true"` to have the `properties-ref` override those from under `META-INF`.

Edit:

Given your most recent comment, I think that you will need to forgo using the `context` namespace and directly use the Spring objects that is uses behind the scenes. Perhaps something like this:

In applicationContext.xml:

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location" value="classpath*:META-INF/spring/*.properties" />
</bean>
```

In testContext.xml:

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurerTest" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer" parent="propertyConfigurer">
    <property name="properties" ref="simulatedTomcatProperties" />
    <property name="localOverride" value="true" />
</bean>
<util:properties id="simulatedTomcatProperties">
   <prop key="cfmt.applicationBaseUrl">localhost:8080/cfmt</prop>
</util:properties>
```

I'm guessing you want the local properties to override the properties defined from the classpath resources so I defined `localOverride` as true.

Comment: no unfortunately this does not help. I fare as I understood, the problem is that if I have two `context:property-placeholder` definitons I also have to property place holder, and there are not merged.

Comment: I would expect that the one in `testContext.xml` would override the one in `applicationContext.xml` if it is loaded 2nd. What is the incorrect behavior that you are seeing?

Comment: Is is not incorrect, it is expected (that it does not work with two context:property-placeholder). The behavior is, that the field annotated @Value(${cfma.applicationUrl}) is not populated in the tests. -- I am searching for a way to "extend" the property-placeholder from the applicationContex.xml in my testContext.xml.

Answer (score 3):

If, in your main applicationContext.xml, you specify several property lookups as listed below using a PropertiesFactoryBean, any missed properties files are not loaded, and the last successfully loaded properties file is used. In your case, default.properties (e.g. your test properties file) would be loaded, and because the second file:${catalina}... wouldn't be loaded, your @Value fields would be injected with values specified in default.properties.

Answer taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6375016/spring-properties-file-setting-default-values):

```
<bean id="myProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
   <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true" />
   <property name="locations">
      <list>
        <value>classpath:default.properties</value>
        <value>file:${catalina.home}/webapps/myProperties.properties</value>
      </list>
   </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: So the difference of your suggestion and `<context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:META-INF/spring/*.properties"/>` is not so much. - At least you suggest to have an additional properties file for the tests - right?

Comment: Exactly. And you could also extend the PropertiesFactoryBean to more closely match your needs; I use it to help me load different config files depending on what I'm doing (e.g. using JNDI for lookups, or using a local H2 database, seeding with DBUnit, etc...)

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by splitting up the `applicationContext.xml` in two files:
 - `applicationContext.xml` -- contains the "normal" bean, but NO include of `applicationContext-properties.xml`
 - `applicationContext-properties.xml` -- contains the property placeholder config

`applicationContext-properties.xml`:

```
 <bean class="org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer">
      <property name="locations" value="classpath*:META-INF/spring/*.properties" />
      <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="false" />
 </bean>
```

The web application loads both files on startup:

`web.xml`:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath*:META-INF/spring/applicationContext*.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

For my tests I have added a propoperties file: `simulatedTomcat.test-properties` that contains all the tomcat properties. *note: that this file does not match the pattern used by the properties placeholder configurer of `applicationContext-properties.xml`*

Then I have an properties placeholder configurer for my test that load both kind op properties files (`*.properties` and `*.test-properties`)

`test-context.xml`

```
<import resource="classpath:/META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml" />
<bean class="org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
   <property name="locations">
      <list>
         <value>classpath*:META-INF/spring/*.properties</value>
         <value>classpath*:META-INF/spring/*.test-properties</value>
      </list>
   </property>
</bean>
```